# Copy current URL and save it to TXT with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a button on a HTML page, when I click the button, a JavaScript function have to copy the current URL and write to an already existing TXT file, and overwrite it's current data.

I tried this code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");

// Attach a click event listener to the button
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Wait 0.2 seconds before executing the function
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Get the current URL
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        // Open or create the text file and overwrite its current data
        var file = new File([currentURL], "URLs.txt", {type: "text/plain", overwrite: true});
        // Copy the contents of the file
        file.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: The browser cannot change your local files without permission. Either you paste the contents manually on the file, or download a txt file with the URL as its contents.

Comment: and how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Call the following function with the text file content:

```
function downloadTxtFile(content) {
    var aElem = document.createElement("a");
    aElem.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(content);
    aElem.setAttribute("download", "filename.txt");
    
    aElem.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(aElem);
    aElem.click();
    aElem.remove();
}

downloadTxtFile("https://google.com.br");
```

You can change the function to get the filename. In this form, it only gets the content of the file, which is the URL.